# Saving the data transferred along with the drag and drop of controls

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, save

I have two lists of type 'panel' and I am dragging elements of one list and dropping into the other list. I am successfully able to the visible drag and drop but the actual data transfer is not happening like if save it after drag and drop and when reopen the changes are not shown,the drag and dropped panel is still in the first panel as drag and drop never being done to it. please guide.

In the code below,heading_wise is a list which itself has another list ,project_panels. example to explain the task,Suppose we want to move heading_wise[0].project_panels[0] to heading_wise[1], its showing visually that drag and drop has happened but the project_panel[0] is still stored in heading_wise[0].

```
heading_wise.Last().project_panels.Last().p1.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(p1_MouseDown);
heading_wise.Last().head.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(head_DragDrop);

void head_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {

        int i = (sender as FlowLayoutPanel).TabIndex;

        Control c = e.Data.GetData(e.Data.GetFormats()[0]) as Control;
        if (c != null)
        {
            heading_wise[i].head.Controls.Add(c);

        }  
    }

    void p1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        Control c = (sender as Control);

        //MessageBox.Show(c.Text);

        c.DoDragDrop(c, DragDropEffects.Move);  
    }
```

Comment: how/where are you saving the changes?

Comment: XML, and my doubt is ,do I have to manually save the the changes in the two list or it can be done automatically with the drag and drop.

Comment: I've never done it before personally, but I would imagine you need to save it yourself. You've moved the panel to the other heading, but that's only in memory. Since you've added it to the new location now, you can probably iterate through the `Controls` of that 'heading' to get the new list to save.